# wxpython wx.AboutBox single instance

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm still in the process of learning more about WxPython and I ran into a simple problem.

I like the wx.AboutBox class that manages how credits, licensing and other info is displayed to the user...and I'm not looking forward to building my own from scratch...although I can.

The problem here is that let's say I click on a button which brings up an AboutBox...seems like if you keep on clicking that exact button then multiple instances of the same AboutBox is brought up...and you end up multiple windows that just looks awkward in my opinion. As far as I've looked into it...there's no way to call the **ShowModal()** function that would allow you to get the ID of the close button in the aboutbox template and do some processing to make sure that only one instance is running.

I want to know how to stop this issue from happening...I want a single instance of wx.AboutBox and if it's not possible with this class due to it's nature/limitations then I'll have to consider building my own as a last resort.

Thanks

Comment: Which operating system are you using?  On Windows, an AboutBox is modal.  However, on Linux there seems to be an issue with the underlying wx binding of GTK.  See the thread at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1559067

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own AboutBox dialog is pretty easy. Here's an article that shows one way to do it: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/06/11/wxpython-creating-an-about-box/ or you could just use a GenericMessageDialog too. See the wxPython demo or http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/10/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-2-of-2/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't solved this problem yet. In wxPython, there's a class called "SingleInstanceChecker". I think this is what you're looking for.

http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/SingleInstanceChecker.html